# Safari mobile transform-style flat not working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have been experiencing a weird transform-style bug(?) where an after element clips through text while transform-style is set to flat.

I made a CodePen showing the problem.
Left: transform-style: flat; (what i would like in all browser to look like, only does not in safari mobile)
Right: transform-style: preserve-3d; (how it looks on both sides on mobile)

```
transform-style: preserve-3d; // how it displays on safari mobile
transform-style: flat; // how i would like to display it on safari mobile
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRKjZw
Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out.  I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(0deg);
transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
```

Comment: Safari doesnt need the `-webkit-` prefix for transform any longer